# Orthanc anonymize dcm file, is there a way to directly convert dcm file without generate an anonymized file first

Tags: pydicom

From the official web site of Orthanc, we may find that the way Orthanc anonymize the file:

```
curl http://localhost:8042/instances/6e67da51-d119d6ae-c5667437-87b9a8a5-0f07c49f/anonymize -X POST -d '{}' > Anonymized.dcm
```

So this step will create a anonymized dcm file.

---

**My problem**:

Let's say on my hard disk is a dcm file, I need to do anonymize on it, base on the Orthanc official web site work flow, what I need to do is:

1. Upload the dcm file to Orthanc
2. Create a new anonymized dcm file
3. Upload the new dcm file and delete the old dcm file from Orthanc

---

**My question**:

Is there a way to directly convert the dcm file into anonymized format in Orthanc?

Comment: I also tried to use pydicom to solve this problem, so after read in the dcm file and done the anonymization by using pydicom, it seems I still need to output the anonymized file first and then upload to Orthanc.

Comment: Could you expand your the question part of your post? What do you mean by directly? Do you wish to anonymize the file in your hard disk, without uploading it to Orthanc? Or do you wish to anonymize the file in the Orthanc server, without having to reupload and delete the old instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as explained in the [Orthanc Book](http://book.orthanc-server.com/users/anonymization.html#anonymization-of-patients-studies-or-series), if you anonymize the parent patient, study or series, the resulting anonymized resource will be stored in Orthanc. If you want to anonymize a single instance then upload it, you can contribute to the Orthanc project by creating a [dedicated plugin](http://book.orthanc-server.com/plugins.html).